# Need to add a column in one dataset from another dataset while keeping values intact

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have two dataframes, df and df1 whereas

df:

| sr. | name | sector |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | newyork2510 | 2 |
| 1 | boston76w2 | 1 |
| 2 | chicago785dw | 1 |
| 3 | san891dwn39210114 | 1 |
| 4 | f2391rpg | 1 |

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
  'sr.': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
  'name': ['newyork2510', 'boston76w2', 'chicago785dw', 'san891dwn39210114', 'f2391rpg'],
  'sector': [2, 1, 1, 1, 1]
})
```

and then in df1 I have

| code | class |
| --- | --- |
| bo2510 | 2 |
| on76w2 | 1 |
| bio5dw | 1 |
| tin018 | 1 |
| retm11 | 1 |

```py
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
  'code' : ['bo2510', 'on76w2', 'bio5dw', 'tin018', 'retm11'],
  'class': [2, 1, 1, 1, 1]
})
```

I want to add column "code" into df that it should look exactly like it has values in df1

| sr. | name | sector | code |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | newyork2510 | 2 | bo2510 |
| 1 | boston76w2 | 1 | on76w2 |
| 2 | chicago785dw | 1 | bio5dw |
| 3 | san891dwn39210114 | 1 | tin018 |
| 4 | f2391rpg | 1 | retm11 |

I am trying but without success

```py
df['code'] = df1['code'].values
```

Comment: `df['code'] = df1['code'].values`. This code works. What is the problem?

Comment: Get this error:
```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
...
   3080                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3081             except KeyError as err:
-> 3082                 raise KeyError(key) from err
   3083 
   3084         if tolerance is not None:

KeyError: 'code'
```

Comment: Check of space and non-printable characters in `df1` column names: `df1.columns`